# avoiding very long type arguments in List & Map using '?' keyword in java

Tags: java, generics

I've been working on a class where i encountered Maps and List with very huge Type values.
for e.g.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, ...>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

and

```
List<List<Map<String,...>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

looping over such datatypes makes boilerplate code looks very ugly!

```
for(Map<String, Map<String, ...>> e : map.entrySet()){
    //do something...
    for(Map<String, ..> e1 : e.entrySet()){
       ..more such loops
    }
}
```

I came up with a solution to reduce the size of the template using '?' keyword
below is my solution

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Long>>> map = ....

for(Entry<String, ?> e : map.entrySet()){
    Map<String , ?> mapLevel1 = (Map<String, ?>)e.getValue();
    for(Entry<String, ?> e1 : mapLevel1.entrySet()){
        Map<String, ?> mapLevel2Map = (Map<String, ?>) e1.getValue();
        for(Entry<String, ?> e2 : mapLevel2Map.entrySet()){
            Long data =  (Long)e2.getValue();
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

could there be any potential problems in going with this approach ?
Thanks in Anticipation !

Comment: the one with wildcards is ugly AND unintelligible. Use streams api to make your code cleaner.

Comment: Create classes instead to represent what it is instead of using generic maps right away.

Comment: If you use Java8, you could use streams to keep the type system guarantees and limit type annotations, so you could lower down the boilerplate. However, you'd have to be familiar with java 8 streams... ;)

Comment: @sumit Since you've just accepted the answer and I was reminded about this, there is of course a better alternative these days. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyRomanov, I see var will really help in this case. Thanks for updating the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` means "some type, but I don't know which" (approximately). Since you do know what the type is, it isn't really suitable.

> could there be any potential problems in going with this approach

The casts you need everywhere after `getValue` (and don't need without `?`) are a very significant problem and I wouldn't even call it "potential". If any part of the type changes, good luck finding which casts you need to change and to what.

EDIT: since Java 10, you can just do

```java
for(var e : map.entrySet()){
    var mapLevel1 = e.getValue();
    for(var e1 : mapLevel1.entrySet()){
        var mapLevel2Map = e1.getValue();
        for(var e2 : mapLevel2Map.entrySet()){
            // or var again
            Long data = e2.getValue();
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

and let the compiler deduce types and check everything makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, using `?` is worse.  Don’t do it.

You should enable all compiler warnings in your IDE (or use `-Xlint`, if building on the command line).  That will inform you that casting to generic types is an unsafe operation.

A good way to keep things clean is to create actual data classes which encapsulate those Maps.

For instance, you might replace this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

with this:

```
Person person = new Person();
```

supported by these three classes:

```
public class Person {
    private final Map<String, Address> addressesByType = new HashMap<>();

    public Set<String> getAddressTypes() {
        return new HashSet<>(addressesByType.keySet());
    }

    public Address getAddress(String type) {
        return addressesByType.get(type);
    }

    public void addAddress(String type,
                           Address address) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(type);
        Objects.requireNonNull(address);
        addressesByType.put(type, address);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class Address {
    public static final String TYPE_HOME = "Home";
    public static final String TYPE_WORK = "Work";

    private final Map<String, Vehicle> vehiclesByType = new HashMap<>();

    public Set<String> getVehicleTypes() {
        return new HashSet<>(vehiclesByType.keySet());
    }

    public Vehicle getVehicle(String type) {
        return vehiclesByType.get(type);
    }

    public void addVehicle(String type,
                           Vehicle vehicle) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(type);
        Objects.requireNonNull(vehicle);
        vehiclesByType.put(type, vehicle);
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
public class Vehicle {
    public static final String TYPE_PERSONAL = "Personal";
    public static final String TYPE_BUSINESS = "Business";

    private final Map<String, Boolean> inspectionsByDate = new HashMap<>();

    public Set<String> getInspectionDates() {
        return inspectionsByDate.keySet();
    }

    public Boolean getInspectionOutcome(String date) {
        return inspectionsByDate.get(date);
    }

    public void addInspection(String date,
                              boolean outcome) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(date);
        inspectionsByDate.put(date, outcome);
    }
}
```

Your loops would then look like this:

```
for (String addressType : person.getAddressTypes()) {
    Address address = person.getAddress(addressType);
    for (String vehicleType : address.getVehicleTypes()) {
        Vehicle vehicle = address.getVehicle(vehicleType);
        for (String date : vehicle.getInspectionDates()) {
            boolean outcome = vehicle.getInspectionOutcome(date);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

(The above is just an example.  Obviously, in real life, the keys would be enum values, the dates would be [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) or [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects, and people can have more than one address and more than one vehicle for a particular purpose.)

You can encapsulate Lists in a similar manner;  see, for example, [NodeList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html).

Answer (score 2):

> could there be any potential problems in going with this approach ?
>   Thanks in Anticipation !

A not readable code and a losing of the generics benefit as you have to cast values returned by `Map` methods, as if you used a raw type.

In any case, having a so important deep structure may create runtime errors because of potential instantiation missing and makes code complex to read and maintain.

You should improve your design and introduce custom classes that wrap the maps and provide logic methods to add and retrieve data.
You should also consider library as Guava. 
[Table](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) is for example a good candidate to bring a some abstraction in your manipulated types.